# Hortonworks Kerberos: KRBError: error code is 14

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

After upgrading a kerberized Hortonworks Cluster from 2.5.3 to 2.6.1, all services (hdfs, hive, spark, zookeeper etc) are failing to get credentials via Kerberos with the following errors:

```
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Jun 14 11:52:10 CEST 2017 1497433930000
         suSec is 825974
         error code is 14
         error Message is **KDC has no support for encryption type**
         sname is krbtgt/BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM@JUST.EXAMPLE.COM
         msgType is 30
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: no tgt; searching thru capath
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: no tgt; cannot get creds
KrbException: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds
```

The /etc/krb5.conf file hasn't changed (and it has been working before the upgrade):

```
[libdefaults]
 renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = true
  default_realm = BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM
  ticket_lifetime = 10h


[domain_realm]
  .EXAMPLE.com = JUST.EXAMPLE.COM
  .BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.com = BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM
  BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.com = BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM

[realms]
  BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM = {
    admin_server=MACHINE1.EXAMPLE.com
    rdns = false
    kdc = MACHINE1.EXAMPLE.com
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
  }

[capaths]
        JUST.EXAMPLE.COM = {
                BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM = .
        }
```

The Trust looks like this:

```
addprinc -e "aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal arcfour-hmac:normal" krbtgt/BIGDATACLUSTER.EXAMPLE.COM@JUST.EXAMPLE.COM
```

This is what we've tried:

- Verified Java and JCE , all ok
- Regenerated all Keytabs and restarted Cluster
  *- Checked the "The other domain supports Kerberos AES Encryption" checkbox for the Trust, it's checked.*

Please see the answer. It seems this last point had been the problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity: the (fragment of) Kerberos traces show an error message issued by a KDC for realm "Just", which is not defined in `[realms]` (it's found via a DNS alias and has no specific params). Do you have any control on that KDC, i.e. can you access the server-side logs?

Comment: Good catch, the error was because of a cross-realm issue on the other realm. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally fixed it.

Although I wrote in my question that we had 'Checked the "The other domain supports Kerberos AES Encryption" checkbox for the Trust, it seems that that checkbox has been changed since then (no one can explain how or why). That is what caused the AES encryption of our trust to be rejected by the other trust.

Simply setting the checkbox fixed the errors.

[image]